# How to show the "Revert to Saved" menu item in non-document apps

Tags: macos, cocoa, menuitem

When creating a new project in Xcode, the default menu bar in the storyboard has a "Revert to Saved" menu item in the "File" menu. However at runtime, in a non-NSDocument app, the menu item is missing.

Can I make that menu item appear? I have added an action (`-revertDocumentToSaved:`) for it already, which normally helps *enabling* menu items which are disabled, but in this case, the whole item is missing. (Explicitly) returning `YES` from `-validateMenuItem:` did not help either.

I assume this is the case because it is not a document-based app, but surely there must be a way to modify that behavior...?

Answer (score 0):

Connect the action of the menu item to your own action with a different name.